# Create a link with ASP.NET forms passing a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using ASP.NET Webforms and I can't create a hyperlink passing a parameter. What is the correct syntax for that?

If I use:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx") %>'> MyLink </a>
```

It works correctly and shows `www.example.com/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx` to my user, but I need to pass `www.example.com/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx?value=5`

What I need would be something like:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx?value=") %>' + '<%= MyVariable %>' > MyLink </a>
```

EDIT: MyVariable value is inside a HiddenField.

Comment: `ResolveClientUrl("~/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx?value=" + MyVariable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the ResolveClientUrl and MyVariable within the same block:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/MVP/Views/Test/MyPage.aspx?value=") + MyVariable %>' > MyLink </a>
```

Comment: MyVariable is a HiddenField, how would I get the value? Sorry, I will edit my question to include this info. If you edit your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You could write a public method in the code-behind that accesses the field's value, and change MyVariable in the example in my answer to getMyVariable()